# SQL WHERE condition is list and column type is array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a following table

```
**game_table**
FieldName    | DataType
id:          | integer
computed_at: | timestamp with time zone
game_ids:    | ARRAY
person_id:   | integer
```

How can I select all person_id for a list of game_ids (say [21, 32, 40]):

```
Select person_id
From game_table
where [21, 32, 40] in any(game_ids)
```

I want to see if the above list is present in the array then extract the person_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1537b14c047aabd9bd1fe1fd1272f394)

Use the `ANY` operator (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html) for one value:

```
SELECT person_id
FROM game_table
WHERE 21 = ANY(game_ids)
```

For a list of values you could use the `&&` operator (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) which checks for overlapping of two arrays:

```
SELECT person_id
FROM game_table
WHERE '{21, 10}' && game_ids
```